# Laravel auth login not working laravel 10

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, server

hi have script in my localhost and work fine
but when upload to server admin login not working
i have data from DB and session file is create but user doesn't pass to dashboard **home **

**admin Model**

```
class Admin extends Authenticatable implements HasMedia
{
use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable, SoftDeletes, InteractsWithMedia;
protected $table ="admins";
protected $fillable = [
'name',
'email',
'password',
'photo',
'status',
];
}
```

**AuthController**

```
public function dologin(Request $request)
{
$valudation =$request->validate([
'email'=>'required',
'password'=>'required',
'_token'=>'required',
]);
if(auth()->guard('admin')->attempt([
'email'=>$request->input('email'),
'password'=>$request->input('password'),
'status'=>1
])
){
return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::DASHBOARD);
}else{
return redirect()->route('admin.auth.login');
}
}
```

**login Html**

```
<form action="{{ route('admin.auth.attempt')}}" method="post">
@csrf
<div class="form-group">
<label>Email</label> <input class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your email" type="text" name="email">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label>Password</label> <input class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your password" name="password" type="password">
</div><button class="btn btn-main-primary btn-block">Sign In</button>
</form>

Route::group(['prefix'=>'Administration','middleware'=>'auth:admin'], function(){
Route::get('/', [HomeController::class, 'index'] )->name('admin.home');
Route::get('/logout', [AuthController::class, 'logout'] )->name('auth.logout');
});
```

data come from DB from user information will but user didn't open dashboard home

i explain every think but i thins maybe the error from server and the server need configuration?

Comment: The encrypted password is stored in DB? didn;t you need to check `bcrypt($request->input('password'))` insted of `$request->input('password')`?

Comment: The encrypted password is stored in DB? didn;t you need to check `bcrypt($request->input('password'))` insted of `$request->input('password')`?

Comment: @MamaD Laravel's authentication takes care of that with Auth::attempt

Comment: You'll want to do some troubleshooting, especially if it works locally. Does the user exist in the server database, and is the password correct, and is the status set to 1 for that user? Does it throw any errors? You can add some logging to the doLogin function to see where it might be stopping.